# How would I store text in a state that the user wrote using Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

Whenever the user types something in the `<textarea>` and then clicks `submit`, I want to display what they've written in the `alert()` via `handleStorytext()` function.

How can I achieve this and what did I do wrong?

As of now, upon writing something in the `<textarea>` and then clicking `submit`, I an get error which points to `handleStorytext()` saying: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`.

Here's `CreateArticle`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actionType from "../../store/actions/actions";

class CreateArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.articleIdValueRedux(event.target.value);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    handleStoryText(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.value);
        alert("Article saved " + '\n' + this.props.storyTextValue);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="author name"/>
                    <textarea value={this.props.storyTextValue} onChange={this.handleStoryText} rows="2" cols="25" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
        storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value}),
        storyTextValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.STORY_VALUE, value})

    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateArticle);
```

Here's `ArticleIdReducer`:

```
import * as actionType from '../store/actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    storyTextValue: ''
};

const StoryTextReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionType.STORY_VALUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                storyTextValue: action.value
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default StoryTextReducer;
```

Comment: you are missing bind for handleStoryText. Try adding the binding in constructor and retry. Plus it will be good practice to define your default state with value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you are doing incorrect

1. You are using function in textarea onChange but you are not binding it. You
   need to bind it in constructor always and never bind a function
   directly in render or anywhere else except constructor
2. you need to assign this.state.value to value prop in textarea but you are assigning a prop which isn't exist
3. Also when you do setState the updated state value won't be available immediately before render

The below code works for you in ES5

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actionType from "../../store/actions/actions";

class CreateArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           value: "",
           error: ""
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleStoryText = this.handleStoryText.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.articleIdValueRedux(event.target.value);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    handleStoryText(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});

    }
    onSubmit = () => {
       if(this.state.value === ""){
          alert("Please enter the value and then click submit");
       }else{
           alert("Article saved " + '\n' + this.state.value);
       }
    }
    render() {
        const { value } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="author name"/>
                    <textarea value={value} onChange={this.handleStoryText} rows="2" cols="25" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick={this.onSubmit}/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
        storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value}),
        storyTextValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.STORY_VALUE, value})

    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateArticle);
```

If you hate doing binding in constructor thn use arrow functions. The advantage with arrow function is you no need to bind a function and no need to refer this to a local variable like self for eg. this context is by default available in arrow function

ES6 version code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actionType from "../../store/actions/actions";

class CreateArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           value: ""
        }
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.articleIdValueRedux(event.target.value);
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.value);   
    }

    handleStoryText = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});

    }

    onSubmit = () => {
       if(this.state.value === ""){
          alert("Please enter the value and then click submit");
       }else{
           alert("Article saved " + '\n' + this.state.value);
       }
    }

    render() {
        const { value } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>

                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="author name"/>
                    <textarea value={value} onChange={this.handleStoryText} rows="2" cols="25" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick={this.onSubmit}/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
        storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value}),
        storyTextValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.STORY_VALUE, value})

    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateArticle);
```

Comment: I got what you're saying.  But still whenever I type something in the textarea, the alert prompts up right away after pressing the 1st key.  I want it so that when I'm done typing something in the textarea, then clicking submit should I see the alert prompt containing what I've written.

Comment: I updated my answer as per your requirement. Please give a try now

Comment: I really appreciate the reply.  But the same thing keeps happening, the alert prompt keeps coming up after every press of the key.

Comment: I also think you made a small error, it should be `{this.state.value !== "" && this.alertMessage()}` not `{value != "" && this.alertMessage()}` but I fixed that on my end.

Comment: === is for Data type and value equal check. So using == is not an error.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to show alert only once after user completes typing. The only way is to show alert is after user typing ask user to click on a button to show the alert. That's the only way if you want to prevent alert for only once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180666/discussion-between-sp92-and-think-twice).

Answer (score 0):

when you pass onChange handler functions, the scope of 'this' is lost.

> So, use `onChange={this.handleStoryText.bind(this)}` in your render
>   function

For more info, you can check these [docs](https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480)

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'; import {connect} from
    "react-redux"; import * as actionType from
    "../../store/actions/actions";

    class CreateArticle extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {storyTextValue:""}
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }

        handleChange(event) {
            this.setState({value: event.target.value});
            this.props.articleIdValueRedux(event.target.value);
        }

        handleSubmit(event) {
            this.setState({value: event.target.value});
            this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.value);
              alert("Article saved " + '\n' + this.state.storyTextValue);
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        handleStoryText(event) {
            this.setState({storyTextValue: event.target.value});
            this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.value);
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        render() {
            return(
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                        <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="author name"/>
                        <textarea value={this.props.storyTextValue} onChange={this.handleStoryText} rows="2" cols="25" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            );
        } }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
            storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue
        }; };

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
             articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value}),
             storyTextValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.STORY_VALUE, value})

         }; };

     export default connect(mapStateToProps,
     mapDispatchToProps)(CreateArticle)

;
```

Comment: got it, but now everytime I type something inside textarea, the alert prompt keeps coming up. how do I make it come up only when I'm done typing what I need to type and then clicking submit so that I can see what I wrote in alert?

Comment: you can use onBlur event, instead on onChange. or you can call this function(handleStoryText) in handleSubmit

Comment: I tried that, it won't even let me type anything in the textarea when I use onBlur

Comment: Thats because onChange is not handled. Do setState in onChange and alert in onBlur

Comment: sorry sir, I don't understand what you mean by that.   may you please write it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180659/discussion-between-sp92-and-chaitanya-mankala).

Comment: Never recommend to bind a function directly in render